# What is the Chinese equivalent of "Encl." used in formal letters?

Tags: formal

What is the Chinese equivalent of "Encl." used in formal, written correspondences to alert the recipient of the presence of enclosed documents?

Comment: `附件：` or `附：` is OK.

Answer (score 2):

随信附上 or 附件

Here is a webpage of baidu(an chinese website) zhidao (pinyin, which means know) which explains Encl. in chinese and english.
http://zhidao.baidu.com/question/40359245.html
Hope it is helpful. :)

Comment: Actually the link only explains what Encl. means in English. It doesn't provide any further example or explanation of the Chinese usage.

Answer (score 2):

Encl. means "附件 (fù jiàn)" in Chinese. You can say 请查看附件 (qǐng chá kàn fù jiàn) means "Please check the enclosed files" in English to alert your recipient.